# Facebook API OAuth security

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to allow users connect to my website using their facebook account.
First, the user authorizes my application and then I get an access token. Problem is, that I'm supposed on the first time to register the user, and the next time to auto login him based on his facebook email.

How do I create a *SECURE* way to auto login the user?
I'm using pure javascript, but I can't find any way to create a secure mechanism.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook should handle all that for you - when they come back to your website, they can click the 'login' button(javascript SDK) and facebook should pass you back an access token.

I may, however, have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yes, but once users has been registered, how do I make auto login? I firstly check if the email exists, if not - it's the first time he's using the connect, if it exists - I should auto login him according to the email address. the javascript sdk is not secure to post variables like that (I thought about getting the access token and then posting from my server to verify the email)

Comment: Why don't you think the SDK is secure for this? My use of the SDK is rusty, but I think a combination of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ alongside https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/ should do what you want

Comment: OK, but I need to verify an email on my side. It means the email is being sent somehow, and javascript is easy to manipulate. It has to be something like getting an access token + email (via JS), then forcing my server to send the access token to facebook and compare if received email equals to previous one (so the user isn't hacking)

Comment: that what I finally did... got access token -> GET request with it to me/?access.... --> got the details from Facebook by server and not client